# Is it worth it to buy an iPhone instead of iPod Touch mainly for testing for mobile layout?

Tags: mobile

I was planning to buy an iPod Touch or iPhone but Im not sure which one

I'm a web designer and do some coding too and currently I'm planning to create some site design mainly for mobile, and I cant find tester for PC (I've already done my research, but can't find any accurate at the moment).

So I decided to make a plan to buy an iPhone or iPod Touch, just for this.

My question is: is buying an iPhone worth it? or maybe an iPod Touch instead since it's cheaper? what do you think guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all fairness, they both use the same browser, the screensize won't differ amazing amounts, and the price of on iPod touch is considerably less in comparison with an iPhone, so i'd get the touch, if your only getting one for that reason then the iPod touch is definately worth it, otherwise, save some cash and use a simulator that Radu suggested.

Here's a link to one:
http://www.testiphone.com/

I don't know if its of any brilliance seeing as I have never used one to be fair, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: I was talking about Apple's iPhone simulator.

Comment: I know, thats why I said "save some cash and use a simulator that Radu suggested."

Comment: thanks for mentioning the screensize , I thought both phone have different screensize thats why I ask this question, thanks again man, I'll pick this as my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the iPhone simulator.

[image]
<sub>(source: [webstockbox.com](http://www.webstockbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/iphone_browser.png))</sub>

Comment: hey man ,any links? just curious ...is that'iphone simulator' an app?, thanks

Comment: @arnold, it comes with [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which is free.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with it. If you plan on using the device as your phone, then buy an iPhone. If you have a phone and are happy with it, buy an iPod touch. It's thinner and lighter.

You can also save money, download [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) and use the [iPhone tester](http://iphonetester.com/).